# QLinkedList operator+ efficiency

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, operators, operator-overloading

I am finding myself concatenating `QLinkedLists` a lot, so I am getting concerned about the efficiency of Qt's `QLinkedList::operator+( const QLinkedList<T> &other ) const`

I tried to look up the source code for the `operator+`, but I couldn't make much sense of it.  I've asked for help on that in [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17240766/2062384).

Is using the `operator+()` operator to concatenate two `QLinkedList`s of the same type efficient?  Does the implementation just have the iterator skip from the first list to the second list, so basically there is no penalty for calling `operator+()?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I found:

```
template <typename T>
QLinkedList<T> QLinkedList<T>::operator+(const QLinkedList<T> &l) const
{
    QLinkedList<T> n = *this;
    n += l;
    return n;
}
```

So it makes a copy of the entire list, uses the operator+=() and returns the new list.  For a const method, it's as straight-forward as it gets.

But I do have concerns:

If you're trying to **merge** large lists... I would personally use std::list instead.   In other words, there are many cases where you don't need to keep a copy of both lists (the subsets) and this is where the penalties are.

```
QList a, b, c;
// ... etc.. assumes a & b grow to great sizes
c = a + b;
```

From the example above, if you need to keep a & b around, then it's clearly a necessary cost to create a new list from the subsets.  But if you don't need a & b after list c has been created... then using the operator+ is not optimal.  And of course - for really small lists this is all trivial.

The std::list container that is [similar to QLinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602036/qvector-vs-qlist).

For std::list, I'd use something like [splice to merge two lists together](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/).  I can't find anything similar for [QLinkedList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qlinkedlist.html), but like I already said, I do tend to favor STL containers in my own code.